# Why do we need to use the 'use namespace;' in Laravel to require a class?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

What is the logic behind composer autoloading? How does it map the namespace to a specific file and why do we always need to use the namespace of that class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What is the logic behind composer autoloading?
> 2. How does it map the namespace to a specific file?
> 3. Why do we always need to use the namespace of that class?

Answers:
3. In many programming language **namespace** used to separate classes that have the same name, but different hierarchy - best example for this is [Eloquent Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) and [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html). Well, think of it as some sort *'file path'* like in your hard disk, you had let's say, file named `b.txt` in directory `dir-a` and `dir-b` but they retains their own contents right? Anyway, it doesn't hurt to read [the php documentation regarding namespace](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php)

(1, 2). Composer reads `composer.json` to check which path represent a namespace and **list every** php files in it and store them into `autoload_*.php` (if you ask me where the file located, it just inside your `/vendor/composer/` everything with `autoload` at the beginning of its name. Laravel - or rather [Composer](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php#L440) - knows how to load them and where they are located through these files. If you check the files you'll have an idea. The *only* convention in Composer's autoload that you need to remember is a single file only for a single class and it's class name should be exact same with file name (without php part - yes, this related to `PSR-*`)

ps. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: How does it read the namespace used and how does it convert it into a path? It reads the file as a text and then finds the keyword 'use'?

Comment: regarding the keyword `use` and `namespace` it's strictly up to the php. Composer only handles which namespace on what file path, contains what classes and such - it only list them, [example](https://bitbucket.org/BagusTesa/ashadi-delivery-system-ads/src/f4bfdca18e87b3c38b802359b3c30db45d99ba2e/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default).

Comment: Yes, but if I don't use 'use' it says class not found. That means that somehow it is converted to a full path through a logic.

Comment: @bruce for example if you take a look at `/vendor/composer/` directory, you will see the generated files containing array with mapping for each namespace to path

Comment: @meda Yes I understand that. I am asking for the other way around. After processing e.g. a Controller,  how does it convert the namespaces used into full paths.

Comment: @bruce, in reality, Composer nor Laravel handle the keyword `namespace` and `use` by itself. it only _include_ whatever files being listed. can you take a look on [`/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php`](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php#L440)?

Comment: @bruce it resolve it using the same hierarchy as the directories (filesystems), `Foo\Bar\Class1` class would be in `Foo/Bar/` folder

Comment: @BagusTesa, Based on the example of ClassLoader.php it converts the namespaces into full paths. How does it achieve that? It reads the php file as a text and then finds the text after each 'use' keyword?

Comment: it only `include`s those file listed in `autoload_*.php` - look for php [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) - that essentially register those file to php runtime. anyway, have you clicked that blue [`/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php`](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/src/Composer/Autoload/ClassLoader.php#L440) link i gave you earlier..?

Comment: Yes I have clicked it. And it says that a class map happens. A namespace is mapped to a full path. My question is: How does this class map happens? How can a 'use' starement be processed and converted to an include?

Comment: well, `Composer` actually did nothing regarding the keyword `use`, it only loads all specified classes (hence autoload) via `include` keyword in `php`. Then whenever `php` needs a certain class, it'll know that the class with that namespace already included. regarding the construction of the autoload files, i can't say much in easy way.. as it's pretty much related with a lot of rules or convention (`PSR-*`) as meda explained in the another answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you use `autoload` alone this means it holds no scope (`namespace`).

This means that if you ever install third party dependencies that classes with the same name in the vendor folder (most likely there will be), there will be a conflict that results into an error fatal to your applications.

Composer class autoload feature also conforms to [PSR-4 Standards](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/).

How does Composer map the files ?

This is specified in the `composer.json` file, for example:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

`App` would be the namespace, and `src` would be the folder

It is also useful for unit test, you can do the following just for development environment:

```
  "autoload-dev":{
    "psr-4" : {
      "App\\Test\\": "tests/"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Yes, but how does it map the namespace to a specific file?

Comment: @bruce I just expanded my answer on that